# I used a scam DEX will I lose all my tokens

Tags: metamask

I connected to a dex I thought was uniswap but it was a fake copy. I paid $120 for some tokens which I never received. My main worry now is whether I have compromised my metamask account and could the malicious site steal all my other tokens? I have already disconnected my account from the site.

Answer (score 1):

The CEX can only steal your tokens if you have either approved it to use your tokens or directly transferred your tokens to it. And if you have approved/transferred token A, it can't steal token B.

Disconnecting your metamask from the site has little effect, since the "connection" doesn't give any special access to your wallet anyway - it basically only gives your public address to it. But, of course, disconnecting doesn't hurt either.